# display just blanks on Daily apt upgrade and clean activities

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

Happened to me already twice, that while working in my laptop my screeen just goes blank, fans speed up and nothing seems to help except a hard sutdown.

I tried to inspect the logs on my own what happended there. I see some daily cleanup tasks:
`Sep 29 09:15:03 zbook systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...`

For some reason within the nvidia driver gets disabled?
Can anyone explain me what happening there? do I have some corrupt configuration or is it some Bug?

I just provide the syslog from the timeframe:

```
Sep 29 09:15:03 zbook systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook nvidia-persistenced: Received signal 15
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook nvidia-persistenced: Socket closed.
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook nvidia-persistenced: PID file unlocked.
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook nvidia-persistenced: PID file closed.
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (1271)
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 09:15:45 zbook systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
Sep 29 09:15:47 zbook systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 29 09:15:48 zbook systemd[1]: Reloading.
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system hibernate actions...
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook hibernate: nvidia-hibernate.service
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook logger[5970]: <13>Sep 29 09:15:49 hibernate: nvidia-hibernate.service
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook logger[5971]: <13>Sep 29 09:15:49 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook logger[5976]: <13>Sep 29 09:15:49 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "25"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event5  - Video Bus: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "43"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event11 - HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "23"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event12 - HP HD Camera: HP IR Camera: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "52"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event9  - SYNA307B:00 06CB:CD46 Mouse: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event10 - SYNA307B:00 06CB:CD46 Touchpad: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event8  - Wireless hotkeys: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (**) Option "fd" "66"
Sep 29 09:15:49 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) event19 - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook kernel: [ 2529.787789] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: AU Optronics Corporation (DP-0): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook kernel: [ 2529.818732] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: AU Optronics Corporation (DP-0): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook kernel: [ 2530.645277] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: AU Optronics Corporation (DP-0): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:73
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:76
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:74
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:83
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Sep 29 09:15:50 zbook kernel: [ 2530.688412] rfkill: input handler enabled
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook kernel: [ 2530.912804] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: AU Optronics Corporation (DP-0): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 302 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 293 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 307 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 307 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 314 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 320 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 316 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 318 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 322 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 279 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 296 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 296 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 296 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 325 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: (II) libinput: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: SetProperty on 327 called but device is disabled.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1914]: This driver cannot change properties on a disabled device
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook nvidia-sleep.sh[5978]: /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh: Zeile 20: echo: Schreibfehler: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook systemd[1]: nvidia-hibernate.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system hibernate actions.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 29 09:15:51 zbook systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Sep 29 09:16:50 zbook systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 29 09:16:50 zbook systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Sep 29 09:16:50 zbook systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Consumed 6min 34.723s CPU time.
Sep 29 09:17:01 zbook CRON[22130]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 29 09:17:15 zbook acpid: client 1914[1000:1000] has disconnected
Sep 29 09:20:07 zbook kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf4, date = 2023-02-23
Sep 29 09:20:07 zbook kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 6.2.0-33-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-073) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 10:33:52 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1-generic 6.2.16)
```